# How to Build an API (nodejs) selecting (GET) a customer in a JSON list , which allow me to fill a template Form and send the email?

Tags: node.js, json, templates

I need to build a simple API, but I don't how to do it. Now I'm focusing on building it with JSON, nodejs using express I think.

Steps:

1. I want choose an employee in list (JSON) using name or id. So it's a 'GET'.
2. Fill a general template(Html) to personalise it using a 'POST'.( I would like to generate a JSON here as well)
3. And send it by mail.

Select this employee from this JSON file example:

```
{
    "employee":{
             "id":"11"
            "name": "Giselle",
            "town": "texas"  
     },
     {
             "id":"22"
            "name": "Mike",
            "town": "texas"  
     }
}
```

> "Dear {{employee}}, your ID:{{id}} and so on",

and send it by mail.

Still investigating

I have installed nodejs, run a simple server. I have my JSON file and I'm going to do simple get request in JavaScript

But is the API a simple js file or a JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this? You need to have your employees.json next to your server.js file to make sure it is finding the file for reading into your nodejs server.

Now make sure you have nodejs installed on your local machine or a server. Then install the dependicies the script has `npm install express body-parser`

and than run it with `node server.js` in your terminal.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/employees/:query', (req, res) => {
  const query = req.params.query;
  const employees = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('employees.json'));

  const employee = employees.find(
    (emp) => emp.id === query || emp.name.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()
  );

  if (employee) {
    res.json(employee);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Employee not found' });
  }
});


app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
  const { id, name, town } = req.body;
  const emailBody = `Dear ${name}, your ID: ${id} and town: ${town}`;

  // Logic for sending the email goes here

  res.json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

You now can call `/employees/mike` or `/employees/22` to get the employee, and post it to `/send-email` so you can compose the email body and send it via mailserver (external api)

Hope this helps you get started. Please note this is just an example and you need to tweak it to fit your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help dingezz, I see that right now.